# if в цикле в c#

Tags: c#

Проблема такая:
задаю в методе переменную, затем создаю массив,в котором в зависимости от значения счетчика меняются формулы для расчета данных переменных, после всех if, в цикле должно откладываться сумма полученных значений и записываться в массив.
но выдает ошибку.что переменные не описывались(не вычислялись). Подскажите,пожалуйста,как убрать ошибку.
Примерный код привожу ниже.
P.s. требуется if заменить на switch. Но ошибка там также остается.

```
public static void Ar()                                                                              
    {
        double A,B,C,At,q=50;                                                  
        if (q <30)
        {
            A = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            A=...  // какая-то опред. формула. эт неважно
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                A = ...  // какая-то опред. формула. эт неважно
                B = ...  // какая-то опред. формула. эт неважно
                C = ...  // какая-то опред. формула. эт неважно
            }
            if (i == 1)
            {
                A= ...  // какая-то опред. формула. эт неважно
                B = ...  // какая-то опред. формула. эт неважно
                C =...  // какая-то опред. формула. эт неважно
            }
            Array[i] = A+B+C;
            }
    }
```

Comment: так у вас `Array` не определен нигде, что это такое должно быть по вашей задумке?

Comment: Я так понял, что речь идет о переменных `A, B, C`. В месте их объявления явно проинициализируйте их, например, `double A = 0, B = 0, C = 0;` вместо `double A, B, C;` (чтобы компилятор был уверен в том, что данные переменные обязательно будут проинициализированы к моменту их сложения здесь: `Array[i] = A+B+C;`)

Comment: @Grundy это я знаю,не упомянула в описании проблемы просто.. в настоящей проге все норм, все везде задано,но ошибка выдается именно на суммировании. что такие переменные не описаны нигде, хотя в if каждый раз будет присвоено новое значение

Comment: @StateItPrimitive точно. Спасибо! все теперь отлично

Answer (score 7):

Компилятор совершенно справедливо считает, что переменные B и C могут быть не инициализированы, поскольку при объявлении они не получили начальных значений, а инициализируете вы их только при выполнении определенных условий `if (i == 0)` и `if (i == 1)`. Фактически конечно инициализация должна происходить, поскольку цикл у вас от 0 до 2, но компилятор не настолько умен, чтобы это предугадывать в compile-time.

В вашем случае необходимо задать начальное значение для B и С. Либо в каждом `if` прописать формулу `Array[i] = A+B+C;`

Comment: вернее он предполагает, что что-то может произойти и в эти условия код не зайдет